# xl create: unable to retrieve domain configuration error

Tags: xen

I'm working with Xen for the first time, using Alpine Linux as Dom0.

I'm following the [Alpine Linux guide](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Create_Alpine_Linux_PV_DomU) to set up a PV guest in Xen, and I'm receiving the following error:

```
alpine-xen:~# xl create -f /etc/xen/a1.cfg  -c
libxl: error: libxl_mem.c:202:libxl_set_memory_target: unable to retrieve domain configuration: No such file or directory
failed to free memory for the domain
```

I could not find any details about this error online. Could someone help me out with this?

Below are my outputs for `xl list` and `xl info`:

```
alpine-xen:~# xl list
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0 64622    24     r-----      10.8
alpine-xen:~# xl info
host                   : alpine-xen
release                : 4.19.80-0-vanilla
version                : #1-Alpine SMP Fri Oct 18 11:27:53 UTC 2019
machine                : x86_64
nr_cpus                : 24
max_cpu_id             : 31
nr_nodes               : 1
cores_per_socket       : 12
threads_per_core       : 2
cpu_mhz                : 3835.933
hw_caps                : 178bf3ff:f6d8320b:2e500800:244037ff:0000000f:219c91a9:00400004:00000500
virt_caps              : pv hvm
total_memory           : 65466
free_memory            : 128
sharing_freed_memory   : 0
sharing_used_memory    : 0
outstanding_claims     : 0
free_cpus              : 0
xen_major              : 4
xen_minor              : 12
xen_extra              : .1
xen_version            : 4.12.1
xen_caps               : xen-3.0-x86_64 xen-3.0-x86_32p hvm-3.0-x86_32 hvm-3.0-x86_32p hvm-3.0-x86_64
xen_scheduler          : credit2
xen_pagesize           : 4096
platform_params        : virt_start=0xffff800000000000
xen_changeset          :
xen_commandline        : placeholder no-real-mode edd=off
cc_compiler            : gcc (Alpine 8.3.0) 8.3.0
cc_compile_by          : buildozer
cc_compile_domain      : [unknown]
cc_compile_date        : Tue Aug 13 14:24:26 UTC 2019
build_id               : f004ef86de8db93d5fbbb90e9b5fa21a70823d67
xend_config_format     : 4
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you forgot to restrict the memory for dom0 on boot.
Depending on our hardware we need 256M up to 2048M for dom0.

you need to set it in these two files:

## /boot/extlinux.conf

```
...
LABEL xen-vanilla
  MENU LABEL Xen + Linux vanilla
  COM32 mboot.c32
  APPEND xen.gz dom0_mem=256M --- vmlinuz-vanilla root=...
...
```

and

## /etc/update-extlinux.conf

```
...
xen_opts=dom0_mem=256M
...
```